# Insert data from CodeIgniter to VB.NET client

Tags: php, vb.net, codeigniter

I have a PHP CodeIgniter and VB.NET based application.
CodeIgniter functions as a sender of data that will later appear on VB.NET. How do I input data from PHP CodeIgniter to VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy an endpoint where PHP CodeIgniter returns your data.
Direct VB.NET requests to that endpoint.